# How to store a large list of numbers using CloudDeploy?

Tags: list-manipulation, wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

I have spent several frustrating hours trying to store a 15MB list of numbers using CloudDeploy, with no success. 
Here is my code with a small list:

```
data = {1, 2, 3};
URLShorten[CloudDeploy[data, "List", Permissions -> "Public"]]
```

But when I try to download the data, it no longer acts like a list of numbers:

```
cyclesperday = CloudImport["https://wolfr.am/vH2xiTJZ", "List"]
listdata = Flatten[cyclesperday]
```

Comment: This appears to be a new bug in the cloud :) It should work fine without any type argument so I think something's just glitchy.

Comment: Thanks! It works when "List" is replaced by "Package".

Comment: Good to hear, although it really should be working without any argument. Dunno what's wrong with it.

Comment: It might be a good idea to report this to Wolfram then. If it is a real bug, then they can work on it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just reported it to Wolfram.

Comment: @halirutan WRI's response has been added to the original post.

Comment: Would you consider moving this information into an answer? I think it is quite helpful and there is absolutely nothing wrong with answering a question yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what Wolfram Tech Support advised:

For applications like this, I would recommend CloudPut and CloudGet:
(http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudPut.html) 
(http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudGet.html).

```
co = CloudPut[{1, 2, 3}, Permissions -> "Public"];  
CloudGet[co] 
{1, 2, 3}
```

The "List" Import/Export format imports a text file, returning each line as a string or a number. Because "{1,2,3}" in this case is on one line, and is not a number, it is imported as a string. In short, the "List" Import/Export format isn't for Wolfram Language expressions, but instead better suited for individual numbers/strings.

Here is one more piece of helpful advice from Wolfram Tech Support:

CloudPut doesn't store the variable name, only the data. As such you'll need to reassign the variable when performing your CloudGet, if you want to use the same variable names:

```
cyclesamples = CloudGet["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/heaneym/cyclesamples"];
forcedata = CloudGet["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/heaneym/forcedata"];
```